# Qt when building Qt from source how do I clean old configure configurations?

Tags: qt, configure

I'm compiling Qt from source, but I don't want to extract the source each time I want to build it.

How can I clean previous configuration with the configure tool?

Comment: make confclean works, but the cleanest and safest option is to build outside of the source tree: mkdir build && /path/to/source configure ... && make && make install

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Qt4 and earlier, try this:

```
nmake confclean
```

You can then re-configure and re-compile QT.

As noted in the comments, this no longer works in QT 5. This is due to the fact that the Qt project now uses separate sub-modules for different parts. If you have a local clone of the Qt git repos, you can try calling this from the main Qt directory:

```
git submodule foreach --recursive "git clean -dfx"
```

As noted [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/6120), there may be some problems if you have a downloaded source archive. The link I posted suggests using a shadow build instead so the process of making a clean configuration is as simple as configuring to build at a new shadow build destination.

Comment: im getting : Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 9.00.30729.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'confclean'
Stop.

Comment: you should call this from qt root directory

Comment: This no longer works.

Is there a way to clean Qt configuration for Qt 5.0+?

Comment: updated post to link to another post discussing Qt5. I'll update again once I've moved to Qt5 (still using Qt4.8 so I'm not familiar with the details yet).

Answer (score 5):

As of today (Qt 5.9.0 beta2) there is no `confclean` target in Linux, and you need to manually remove `.config.cache` file to reconfigure.

Note that `make distclean` doesn't help at all.

Comment: Thanks, it works with 5.9.x. I have no idea why they removed it but then again I've seen much worse decision made by the Qt company regarding the libraries.

Comment: On linux with Qt 5.9.x file is called `config.cache`

Comment: @uglide comment seems to be right about `config.cache`. anyway, thanks the answer worked

Answer (score 2):

For the latest versions, use a shadow build, then you can just nuke your directory. My batch file for configuring effectively creates a new folder, moves into it, then calls configure.
Then you just go into the shadow directory and run 'jom'.
When you want to make a different configuration, just use a different shadow directory.
This effectively means that your source tree doesn't get filled with build artifacts, which are impossible to remove when you want a different configuration.  Trust me, this is the thing to do....

```
mkdir shadow_dir
cd shadow_dir
%~dp0\src\configure.bat ....
```

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu:

```
make confclean
```

BTW, the following text displayed after run configure:

```
Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'make'.
Once everything is built, you must run 'make install'.
Qt will be installed into /home/ben/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-4.7.4-debug

To reconfigure, run 'make confclean' and 'configure'.
```